# QGIS2Web - OSM and one WMS layer disappear when zoomed

Tags: openstreetmap, wms, layers, zoom, qgis2web

I've created a nice map for my work. However, the two layers, both important to me, disappear when zoomed in enough.

One layer (WMS) disappears at 1:500 while the OSM layer at around 1:300. I would need both of these to be active even if zoomed in that much.

Comment: WMS should work at all scales unless they have been configured not to do so, so the issue is probably the client

Answer (score 0):

WMS services are configured on the server that exposes them, so you can't adjust max zoom or min zoom.
As for OSM, don't put it in your project as WMS but as XYZ, you will see the zoom problem will be solved.

To do it copy the URL: [https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)
Then Open Qgis, go to XYZ Tiles >  Right click > New Connection > Paste the URL > Name to the connection
[image]

Then add layer to map and export again with qgis2web